# Is there a way to develop a multisig wallet so that it supports phantom wallet?

Tags: solana-program, wallet

I want to develop a multisig wallet mechanism like the SQUADS protocol. Can I develop a Solana program so that it can support phantom wallet?

Link to the concept of [Smart Contract Wallet](https://blockworks.co/news/what-are-smart-contract-wallets)

Comment: It isn't totally clear what you mean by "support phantom wallet". Wallets support calling any program via a front-end, and this can certainly be done with PDAs, given a proper implementation

Comment: @JoeyMeere as in phantom wallet would show profiles of smart contract wallet just like an EOA address

Answer (score 2):

all smart contracts are supported by every wallet on Solana.
So the only difference you might do is on the client side (Typescript or whatever Entrypoint you have on your app)

Comment: I was talking about smart contract wallet: https://blockworks.co/news/what-are-smart-contract-wallets